# Codeigniter where and or_where coexist?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, where-clause

I am trying to get a `where()` and a `or_where()` in codeigniter to work together with a `AND` in between. I would like my query to look like the below.

```
SELECT fname 
FROM users 
WHERE is_active = 1 AND (
    employee_type = 'graduate' OR employee_type = 'staff' OR employee_type = 'Person Of Interest'
)
```

Here is my current code:

```
$this->db->select($print_data);
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->where(array('is_active' => 1));
$where = '';
$this->db->or_where('employee_type', $search_criteria[0]);
for ($i = 1; $i < sizeof($search_criteria); $i++) {
    $this->db->or_where('employee_type', $search_criteria[$i]);
}
```

Below is the output I am geting. Can anybody help?

```
SELECT fname 
FROM users 
WHERE is_active = 1 OR employee_type1 = 'graduate' OR employee_type1 = 'staff' OR employee_type1 = 'Person Of Interest'`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use or_where in CI as:

```
$this->db->select($print_data); 
$this->db->from('users'); 
$this->db->where(array('is_active' => 1)); 

$this->db->where('employee_type', $search_criteria[0]); // CHANGED

for ($i = 1; $i < sizeof($search_criteria); $i++) { 
    $this->db->or_where('employee_type', $search_criteria[$i]); 
}
```

**Second solution:**

You can also `where_in`. In this case start for loop from 0:

```
$arr = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($search_criteria); $i++) { 
    $arr[] = $search_criteria[$i];
}

$this->db->where_in('employee_type', $arr); // CHANGED
```